# Find values where related must have list of values

Tags: sql, sql-server, database

I'm trying to find a simple solution for my SQL Server problem.

I have two tables look like this:

```
table1
--id
-- data

table2
--id
--table1_id
--value
```

I have some records like this:

```
Table1
+-----------------------+
| id        | data      |
+-----------------------+
| 1         | ?         |
+-----------------------+
| 2         | ?         |
+-----------------------+

Table2
+-----------------------+
|id | table1_id | value |
+-----------------------+
| 1 | 1         | 'a'   |
+-----------------------+
| 2 | 1         | 'b'   |
+-----------------------+
| 3 | 2         | 'a'   |
+-----------------------+
```

Now I want to get table1 with all it's additional values where the relation to table2 has 'a' AND 'b' as values.
So I would get the id 1 of table1.

Currently I have an query like this:

```
SELECT t1.[id], t1.[data]
FROM [table1] t1,
(SELECT [id]
 FROM [table1] t1
   JOIN [table2] t2 ON t1.[id] = t2.[table1_id] AND t2.[Value] IN('a', 'b')
 GROUP BY t1[id]
 HAVING COUNT(t2.[Value]) = 2) x
WHERE t1.id = x.id
```

Has anyone an idea on how to achieve my goal in a simpler way?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One way uses `exists`:

```
select t1.*
from table1 t1
where exists (select 1
              from table2 t2
              where t2.table1_id = t1.id and t2.value = 'a'
             ) and
      exists (select 1
              from table2 t2
              where t2.table1_id = t1.id and t2.value = 'b'
             );
```

This can take advantage of an index on `table2(table1_id, value)`.

You could also write:

```
select t1.*
from table1 t1
where (select count(distinct t2.value)
       from table2 t2
       where t2.table1_id = t1.id and t2.value in ('a', 'b')
      ) = 2 ;
```

This would probably also have very good performance with the index, if `table2` doesn't have duplicates.

Comment: Gordon why not club the two exists using `EXISTS...IN ('a', 'b')`

Comment: @HimanshuAhuja . . . That would be equivalent to `or` rather than `and`.

Comment: I could see you worked it around. Yeah i was too thinking of thaf workaround using IN i knew that was or

Comment: i think second solution is more perfect in case there are multiple values say greater then 10 or 15. In that case instead of writing exist every time , we can take count. right Mr Gordon ?

Comment: @PIG . . . The second solution is easier to generalize.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion, I prefer the second solution of you.
It's easy for me to integrate it in my code with the flexibility to query more than 'a' and 'b'.

I'm a SQL beginner and a little bit affraid of performance with sub queries.
I will try it ;)

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT T1.[id], T1.[data]
FROM table1 AS T1
JOIN table2 AS T2
ON T1.[id]=T2.[table1_id]
JOIN table2 AS T3
ON T1.[id]=T3.[table1_id]
WHERE
T2.[Value] ='a' 
AND T3.[Value] = 'b'
```

As Gordon Linoff suggested, exists clause usage works as well and could be performance efficient depending on the data you are playing with.

Comment: Thanks for your solution, but in my case I have to be flexible how many values I want to query. So it could be not only 'a' and 'b'.
So the query would get for every value a new JOIN what is not what I want.

Answer (score 1):

you have to do several steps to solve the problem:

1. established which records are related to table 1 and table 2 and which of these are of value (A or B) and eliminate the repeated ones with the group by(InfoRelationate )
2. validate that only those related to a and b were allowed by means of a count in the table above (ValidateAYB)
3. see what data meets the condition of table1 and table 2 and joined table 1

this query meets the conditions

```
with InfoRelationate as 
(
    select Table2.table1_id,value 
    from Table2 inner join 
    Table1 on Table2.table1_id=Table1.id and Table2.value IN('a', 'b')
    group by Table2.table1_id,value   
),
ValidateAYB as
(
    select InfoRelationate.table1_id
    from InfoRelationate 
    group by InfoRelationate.table1_id
    having  count (1)=2
)
select InfoRelationate.table1_id,InfoRelationate.value 
from InfoRelationate 
inner join ValidateAYB on InfoRelationate.table1_id=ValidateAYB.table1_id
union all
select id,data 
from Table1
```

[Example code](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/7b05f/43)

Comment: Thanks for the response, but in my opinion this solution is a little to complicated for what I want to achieve. And as in the solution of @Sai it's not that flexible I want it to be.